# 'Start and wait for an approval' action with an 'Approval type' of 'First to respond' returns more than one response

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, approval

**Power Automate action**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/connectors/approvals/#start-and-wait-for-an-approval

**Approval type**

Approve/Reject - First to respond

**Expected Behaviour**

We use the 'out-of-the-box' dynamic content `Outcome` from the Approval Request action:

```
@{outputs('Start_and_wait_for_an_approval')?['body/outcome']}
```

to determine subsequent behaviour in a Power Automate flow, i.e:

- IF `Outcome` is `Approve` do this
- ELSE IF `Outcome` is `Reject` do this

We therefore expected that either `Approve` or `Reject` would be returned from this action.

**Actual Behaviour**

In the scenario where an Approval Request is sent to multiple people, we had an instance where ApproverB approved 2 seconds later than ApproverA.

The response `outcome` was:

```
Approve, Approve
```

Instead of the value provided by the first person who Approved it, i.e:

```
Approve
```

For more context, see other outputs below.

**Question**

Is this a bug?

Isn't the whole point of setting `Approval type` to `First to repond` that it only captures one response?

As a workaround, instead of using `Outcome` to determine the first response:

```
@{outputs('Start_and_wait_for_an_approval')?['body/outcome']}
```

We are going to have to specify the `approverResponse` property of the first object in the `responses` array:

```
@{outputs('Start_and_wait_for_an_approval')?['body/responses'][0]?['approverResponse']}
```

And the same logic to capture the first responder's `Name`, `Email` and `Comments`, i.e:

```
@{outputs('Start_and_wait_for_an_approval')?['body/responses'][0]?['responder']?['displayName']}  

@{outputs('Start_and_wait_for_an_approval')?['body/responses'][0]?['responder']?['email']}  

@{outputs('Start_and_wait_for_an_approval')?['body/responses'][0]?['comments']}
```

**Further Context**

*Response summary*

```
Approver: ApproverB, emailA@domain.com
Response: Approve
Request Date: Monday, May 22, 2023 10:57:21 PM
Response Date: Monday, May 22, 2023 11:10:50 PM <-------------------- Second response, 2 seconds later  

Approver: ApproverA, emailB@domain.com
Response: Approve
Request Date: Monday, May 22, 2023 10:57:21 PM
Response Date: Monday, May 22, 2023 11:10:48 PM <-------------------- First response
```

*Response body*

```json
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "responder": {
        "id": "********",
        "displayName": "ApproverA",
        "email": "emailA@domain.com",
        "tenantId": "********",
        "userPrincipalName": "emailA@domain.com"
      },
      "requestDate": "2023-05-22T22:57:21Z",
      "responseDate": "2023-05-22T23:10:50Z",
      "approverResponse": "Approve",
      "comments": "Here are ApproverA's comments"
    },
    {
      "responder": {
        "id": "********",
        "displayName": "ApproverB",
        "email": "emailB@domain.com",
        "tenantId": "********",
        "userPrincipalName": "emailB@domain.com"
      },
      "requestDate": "2023-05-22T22:57:21Z",
      "responseDate": "2023-05-22T23:10:48Z",
      "approverResponse": "Approve",
      "comments": "Here are ApproverB's comments"
    }
  ],
  "responseSummary": "Approver: ApproverB, emailB@domain.com\r\nResponse: Approve\r\nRequest Date: Monday, May 22, 2023 10:57:21 PM\r\nResponse Date: Monday, May 22, 2023 11:10:50 PM\r\n\r\nApprover: ApproverA, emailA@domain.com\r\nResponse: Approve\r\nRequest Date: Monday, May 22, 2023 10:57:21 PM\r\nResponse Date: Monday, May 22, 2023 11:10:48 PM",
  "completionDate": "2023-05-22T23:10:50Z",
  "outcome": "Approve, Approve", <-------------------- this is problematic  
  "name": "********",
  "title": "REQUEST NAME HERE",
  "details": "Request description here",
  "itemLink": "ITEM LINK HERE",
  "itemLinkDescription": "ITEM LINK NAME HERE",
  "requestDate": "2023-05-22T22:57:08Z",
  "expirationDate": "9999-12-31T23:59:59Z",
  "priority": "Medium"
}
```